Historic Building Floor: radiant, continuous, encapsulating... but upstairs?
I am renovating an historical building c. 1930. The main floor is constructed of cement beams and structural clay tile above a full basement. There are 223 m2 /2400 ft2 per level.
I'm trying to address three issues with this floor:

easy-to-maintain, continuous flooring surface throughout the space (incorporating two staircases)
radiant floor heat (including a bathroom with curbless shower)
encapsulation of existing asbestos tile

I thought it would be relatively simple/affordable to pour concrete on top of the hydronic piping then polish the surface as my finished flooring, but the beam/tile construction is anachronistic, so I'm feeling cautious about introducing a lot of new weight to the structure. I thought it would be only an inch or two thick slab to cover everything, but one person told me it should be 4 inches thick, and that's sure a lot heavier (also perplexing). If it matters, this building was institutional, not residential, so it was built to standards that would have allowed at least 100 people on that floor daily and still be functional 80 years later, but it's not like I have blueprints or anything. I also have not been able to find a structural engineer willing to take the project (it is in a very inconvenient location and a relatively small renovation).
Does anyone have experience with this type of floor construction? Am I being too cautious? Is that 4" slab whack? Are there other solutions I should consider that would address my three goals? I am eager for new ideas and/or reassurance. Thanks for any help.

Concrete is quite weak under 4 inches, any chance of bending and it will crack.  Adding any amount of concrete to a floor should have it designed by someone with experience.  Usually stuff is design to the minimums to save money.  Adding extra weight is iffy, especially if the extra weight requires a forklift to move 4x8 foot sections.

What will the function of the building be?
